# Как написать текст на selenium не в поле input

Tags: python, selenium

Есть программа на selenium. Я дошёл до момента где нужно написать заголовок и текст, но проблема в том что тип там не input, а h1 и p со span в них. Есть ли способ напечатать текст так?
развёртка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S если что у меня останавливается на том что я нажимаю на этот элемент

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send_keys-element-method-selenium-python/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работая с `selenium`'ом вы должны имитировать действия пользователя браузера.

Ваша задача на данном моменте усложняется тем, что вам нужно ввести символы не в текстовое поле, а в элемент с атрибутом `contenteditable` и в данный элемент не так просто ввести текст, его для начала, грубо говоря, нужно "активировать" - кликнув на него мышкой. Тогда фокус и курсор будет перемещен в выбраный элемент и мы можем осуществлять ввод.

В селениуме нам нужно сделать тоже самое

1. Открываем страницу
2. находим элемент
3. кликаем по нему
4. при необходимости стираем вложенные данные
5. вводим текст

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# не забудьте заменить url
driver.get("https://www.your.site/")

# находим элемент на странице
header = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.wp-block-post-title")

# кликаем по нему
header.click()

# вот так можно стереть символ, отправив кнопку BACKSPACE
header.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)

# повторив это столько раз, сколько символов в тексте 
# мы сотрем все что было введено до нас
for i in range(0, len(header.text)):
    header.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)

# а вот так можно ввести что-то своё
header.send_keys("Hello from Selenium!")
```